# What is the function of 802.11 (Retry Field)?

Tags: networking, wifi, wireshark, packet, ieee

I have done some research but I'm still confuse with this field. I know its purpose is for retransmission if the bit is set to 1. However, is it correct for me to say that if the packet is sent but it does not receive acknowledgement back then it will try to send again and thus the bit is set to 1 in Retry field.

Correct explanation? If I am wrong, how do I explain it then?

Answer (score 0):

It is a wireless frame that is re-transmitted because the receiver did not acknowledge it. For detail information refer : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wm9zK7kDvU